# how to get data from two tables of sqlite and sort data

Tags: database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I've two tables

**income**

[image: income]

**expense**

[image: expense]

the problem is I want to query all the data from both tables

```
SELECT income.date AS IN_DATE, expense.date AS EX_DATE FROM income, expense
```

I get weird result data is double times from db as you can see

[image: whole result after query]

you can try this out [HERE](https://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle-58c547cdd0978f3086a7d53f8af47b2faf0d8f31d414f23140)

how can I get distinct results not double and at last wanna ask don't have idea of getting data from both tables and sort by *date* descending.

Comment: Query data from both the tables -- How? What do you mean by that? You are doing a cross join between the two, which is why you are doing repeated results. Do you want a UNION?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you want `union all`:

```
select 'income' as which, id, title, date
from income
union all
select 'expense' as which, id, title, date
from expense;
```

This will give you a result set containing the rows from the two tables, with an identifier of which table each row comes from.

You can order by date and do other manipulations if you use a subquery:

```
select ie.*
from (select 'income' as which, id, title, date
      from income
      union all
      select 'expense' as which, id, title, date
      from expense
     ) ie
order by date desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to match the same ids, else SQL will just output any possible combination.

```
SELECT income.date AS IN_DATE, expense.date AS EX_DATE FROM income, expense WHERE income.id LIKE expense.id
```

Comment: Please would you like to create a fiddle on the https://sqliteonline.com

Comment: I did it on SQLite, but then I changed the "WHERE" to big letters and forgot the E -.-

Answer (score 0):

Your simple `SELECT` does a cross product with the two columns (`IN_DATE, EX_DATE`). Hence, you get every possible combination of the values from both columns. `INNER JOIN income ON expense.id=income.id` or `WHERE income.id == expense.id` should do the trick.